# How to solve "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_D2D1Blend" when using Direct2d Effects?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-store-apps, direct2d

I'm developing a Windows Runtime Component (Visual C++) drawing lib to be used on a Windows Store App C# Project.

Everything was running as expected until I started to add some Effects capabilities to the lib.

When trying to create an effect like bellow:

```
    m_d2dContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1Blend, &m_blendEffect)
```

The following error is shown:

```
    1>MyLibFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_D2D1Blend
```

I already have these pragma comments on my `pch.h`:

```
    #pragma comment(lib, "d3d11")
    #pragma comment(lib, "d2d1")
```

I suspect that some definition is missing but I do not know what as the `#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1")` was already added to the `pch.h`.

I'm running Windows 10 Technical Preview build 9860 and VS Express 2013 update 3 on a virtual machine - VM-Ware.

This is a sample project using effects and direct 2d: [Direct2D-Image-Effects](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct2D-Image-Effects-4819dc5b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands in the [MSDN - Blend Effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706313(v=vs.85).aspx#requirements): `Library - d2d1.lib, dxguid.lib`

You are missing the `dxguid.lib`

Also, you can use the raw GUID: `{81C5B77B-13F8-4CDD-AD20-C890547AC65D}`

Comment: Never hard-code a guid, they change.  Linking to dxguid.lib is enough.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to Windows apps development and I'm not really familiar with the docs. But it was my fault on reading carefully the full doc page, especially the Requirements/library section. Living and learning.